# Does this argument by Aristotle show that identity is not fundamental?

Tags: aristotle, philosophy-of-physics

Atomism remains the paradigm for physical explanations:

There are only atoms and the void within which they move. And the All is made up of their collisions and their combinations.

In this picture, an atom retains its identity. It is it's own self at this time and for all time. An atom is an everlasting element of reality.

Aristotle however argued against this picture. He suggested a thought experiment: what happens if two atoms collide, at the moment of collision are their surfaces in touch with other?

Now, if at this moment the two atoms are seperated by some distance, then they haven't yet collided. So there must be no distance between the two surfaces. But then, at this moment, what right have we to call them two distinct atoms?

This suggests that at this moment atoms lose there identity. But this self-identity is part of defining property of an atom. They are permanent.

It seems we have a contradiction. This either atoms cannot be as they are generally described. At best, sometimes they lose their identity. At worst, it's altogether the wrong picture. It may also suggest that fundamental ground of reality has no self-identity.

What is interesting here, is that in QFT, particles do appear to lose identity: particle number is not conserved.

I'm using the picture of atoms as described first by Democritus. But in the contemporary world atoms are not described as such. They are also the locus of a field. For example, the electron is the source of an EM field. (One might argue, that it is in fact the field, that as a whole is fundamental, and the sources within it are mere parts and so derived).

Can Aristotles argument be made to work in such a context? That is with atoms that are the source of forces, and it is these forces that either attract or repel them?

Comment: Aristotle's argument only works if collision implies touching. As that doesn't apply to fundamental particles, his argument doesn't apply either. BTW I understand why you're using the term atom here but, in modern terminology, atoms don't retain their identity.

Comment: @Alex: I've noted this in the question where I say in QFT particles don't retain identity. Though chemists will probably say that they do.

Comment: Fundamental particles do retain identity. Atoms don't.

Comment: @Alex: Really, what about virtual particles? In the Greek conception of atoms, they wouldn't call an atom of Carbon an atom as they would point out that they can be broken further apart. They would say they were mis-named. They'd call quarks, the atoms, as they can't be further broken down. Or if you believe in strings, then they are the actual atoms.

Comment: What about them? The Greek concept of atoms is too simplistic no matter how you try to shoehorn it in. Not saying it wasn't pretty impressive considering the timing but you can't reasonably apply it to particle physics and expect it to work.

Comment: @Alex: virtual particles show that particle number is not conserved, and so unlike what you say about 'fundamental particles retain identity' - they don't. It was something of a shock for physicists to find out that they didn't. But I think by then they were immured to shocks.

Comment: The point of the notion of an atom is that it's a permanent element of reality, and therefore 'uncuttable'. This is what word means etymologically. Conceptually speaking, and in this sense, quarks, strings or branes are atoms. 'You can't reasonably apply it to particle physics and expect it to work' - I think I just showed how in the question above.

Comment: "I just showed how". No you didn't. You changed the meaning of the words so it sounded less wrong. A neat trick but doesn't stop it being wrong. Aristotle had a conception of physics that was too simplistic. As did pretty much everyone till the beginning of the 20C. His contribution should be lauded, for sure, but this is the philosophical equivalent of "days meant epochs in Genesis".

Comment: Fundamental particles retain identity. I didn't say they were eternal.

Comment: @Alex: You're being simplistic by comparing Aristotles physics directly with todays. Thats just plain wrong. His physics is at the root of physics today. It's like thinking that there is something wrong with studying Newtonian gravity because we have Einsteins theory of gravity.  There's a quote that I came across recently from Newton that shows that Newtonian corpuscules were directly inspired by ancient atomism.

Comment: @Alex: 'Fundamental particles retain identity' - please explain how, because I don't see it and nor have you explained it - you've just asserted it.  Its not how I was explaining identity in the question and it seems you have your notion of this.

Comment: What you call "atomism" is often called "reductionism" by professional philosophers today.  And there are critiques of reductionism, especially coming out of biology, social science, and cognitive science.  I recommend [this SEPh article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reduction-biology/#ProbRedu) and Sandra Mitchell's [*Unsimple Truths*](https://books.google.com/books?id=obbUPu0HbHEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=mitchell,+biological+complexity&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidlOC4quTYAhVW1WMKHbLXDmsQ6AEILjAB)

Comment: @Dan hicks: thanks for your refs, they look interesting.